# How to resolve "Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" in docker?

Tags: java, docker, maven, mqtt, messagebroker

I have a Java Maven application which when ran locally successfully connects to a MQTT broker ran in Docker. The problem is, it is unable to connect when the same Java application is run in a container in docker. This used to work before.

Here is the exception I get:

```
Failed to connect to the MQTT broker with address ws://localhost:9001 Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Here is the Dockerfile of the Java application:

```html
#Required
FROM eclipse-temurin:16

# The jar file that will be run. This is a result of the build process
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

# The dependencies folder for all maven dependencies
ARG DEPENDENCIES=target/dependency/

# Make a directory for the jar
RUN mkdir /src

# Make a directory for the dependencies
RUN mkdir /src/lib

#Make a directoryfor the ServerConfig file 
RUN mkdir -p /src/main/resources
#Echo Jar File
RUN echo $JAR_FILE

# Copy the jar from it's original location to the docker container
COPY acs-simulator/${JAR_FILE} /src/jar/
#Echo Jar File
RUN echo $(ls -1 /src/jar/)


RUN echo pwd

# Copy all of the dependencies of the jar to the docker container
COPY acs-simulator/${DEPENDENCIES} /src/lib

# The entry point is the command the docker container will run when it start, so in this case it will start the jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/src/jar/acs-simulator-latest.jar"]
```

Here is also the MQTT broker config:

```html
## Logging

log_dest stdout
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information

## MQTT Listener

listener 1883
protocol mqtt

## WebSockets Listener

listener 9001
protocol websockets

## Persistence

persistence false
```

Here is how I print the exception:

```html
  @Override
    public void onMQTTConnectionFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken,Throwable throwable) {
        this.logger.log("Failed to connect to the MQTT broker with address " + this.client.getBrokerAddress() + " " + throwable + "   " + iMqttToken ,
                ILogger.LogLevel.ERROR);

        waitAndReconnectToBroker();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `localhost:9001` can you try with `containerIp:9001` , You can get the containerIp with `docker inspect` command

Comment: @Sahit did not help.

Comment: Which container IP did you use? It would need to be the IP address of the mosquitto container, not the java container.